# Is the bilinear form $A(\cdot,\cdot)$ $l_{2}$-elliptic or coercive?

Tags: sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, bilinear-form, coercive

Consider the space $l_{2} = \{ (x_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R} : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_{n}|^{2} < \infty  \}$. Now, consider the bilinear form $A(\cdot,\cdot):l_{2}\times l_{2}\to \mathbb{R}$, which is given by
\begin{equation}
A(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}x_{n}y_{n}\text{,}
\end{equation}
where $(a_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of positive numbers defined by $a_{n} = 2^{-n}$. We know that $l_{2}$ is an inner product space with inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ defined by
\begin{equation}
\langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{n}y_{n}\text{.}
\end{equation}
**Question:** Is the bilinear form $A(x,y)$ coercive? In other words, does there exists $\alpha>0$ such that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}x_{n}^2 = A(x,x) \geq \alpha \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{n}^{2}?
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the reasoning for your argument ?

Comment: If $\sum a_{n}x_{n}^2 \geq \sum \alpha x_{n}^2$ then $\sum (  a_{n} - \alpha) x_{n}^2\geq 0$. Since $x_{n}^2\geq 0$ then $a_{n}-\alpha \geq 0$.

Comment: that's not true. $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2} > 0$ but half the coefficients are negative. Try to choose a specific sequence $\{x_n\}$ that will give you $a_n\geq\alpha$

Comment: @dezdichado Yeah, that's not true. Thank you. Do you think $A(\cdot,\cdot)$ is coercive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no $\alpha > 0$ such that
$$ \tag{*}
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}x_{n}^2  \geq \alpha \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{n}^{2}
$$
for all $x = (x_n) \in \ell_2$. If we fix a positive integer $m$ and choose for $x$ the sequence $(\delta_{m, n})_n$ which is $1$ at position $m$, and $0$ otherwise, then $(*)$ gives
$$
 2^{-m} \ge \alpha > 0
$$
for all positive integers $m$, which is not possible.

A similar argument shows that, given $\alpha > 0$,
$$ 
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n x_{n}^2  \geq \alpha \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{n}^{2}
$$
holds for all $x = (x_n) \in \ell_2$ if and only if $a_n \ge \alpha$ for all $n$. In other words,
$$
A(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}x_{n}y_{n}
$$
is coercive if and only if $\inf \{ a_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \} > 0$.